# VeeValidate 4 configure classes

Tags: vee-validate

I'm having difficulty configuring the error classes in the form, in version 4, in previous versions they were simpler

I hope veevalidator adds the class to the form's input element

```
configure({
        classes: {
            valid: 'is-valid',
            invalid: 'is-invalid',
            dirty: ['is-dirty', 'is-dirty']
        }

    })
```

```
<form is="vue:Form" @submit="onSubmit">
        <Field name="email" type="email" rules="required"></Field>
        <error-message name="email"></error-message>
        <button>Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: solution https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/validation#displaying-error-messages